# Encountering warning `Bounding rectangle error in MKMapView`

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I have a `MKMapView`, I am doing [clustering](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/decluttering_a_map_with_mapkit_annotation_clustering).

I get below error when I load the mapView for the first time.

```swift
2019-04-22 11:05:33.003610+0530 Clustering[3528:57208] [Assert] Bounding path likely out of sync with its coordinate space: The view's bounds must contain the bounding rect. Bounding rect: {{0, 0}, {375, 559}}; coordinate space: <UIScrollView: 0x7fc9f1863a00; frame = (0 0; 375 559); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000024ab000>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ae5380>; contentOffset: {375, 0}; contentSize: {750, 559}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
2019-04-22 11:05:33.003929+0530 Clustering[3528:57208] [Assert] Bounding path likely out of sync with its coordinate space: The view's bounds must contain the bounding rect. Bounding rect: {{0, 0}, {375, 559}}; coordinate space: <UIScrollView: 0x7fc9f1863a00; frame = (0 0; 375 559); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000024ab000>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ae5380>; contentOffset: {375, 0}; contentSize: {750, 559}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
2019-04-22 11:05:33.004344+0530 Clustering[3528:57208] [Assert] Bounding path likely out of sync with its coordinate space: The view's bounds must contain the bounding rect. Bounding rect: {{0, 0}, {375, 559}}; coordinate space: <UIScrollView: 0x7fc9f1863a00; frame = (0 0; 375 559); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000024ab000>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ae5380>; contentOffset: {375, 0}; contentSize: {750, 559}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
2019-04-22 11:05:33.014910+0530 Clustering[3528:57208] [Assert] Bounding path likely out of sync with its coordinate space: The view's bounds must contain the bounding rect. Bounding rect: {{0, 0}, {375, 559}}; coordinate space: <UIScrollView: 0x7fc9f1863a00; frame = (0 0; 375 559); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000024ab000>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ae5380>; contentOffset: {375, 0}; contentSize: {750, 559}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
2019-04-22 11:05:33.015356+0530 Clustering[3528:57208] [Assert] Bounding path likely out of sync with its coordinate space: The view's bounds must contain the bounding rect. Bounding rect: {{0, 0}, {375, 559}}; coordinate space: <UIScrollView: 0x7fc9f1863a00; frame = (0 0; 375 559); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000024ab000>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ae5380>; contentOffset: {375, 0}; contentSize: {750, 559}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
2019-04-22 11:05:33.016501+0530 Clustering[3528:57208] [Assert] Bounding path likely out of sync with its coordinate space: The view's bounds must contain the bounding rect. Bounding rect: {{0, 0}, {375, 559}}; coordinate space: <UIScrollView: 0x7fc9f1863a00; frame = (0 0; 375 559); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000024ab000>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600002ae5380>; contentOffset: {375, 0}; contentSize: {750, 559}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}>
```

What this warning is and how can I fix this warning? Since I assume this warning is messing up with the annotations count.

Comment: I received the same warning when I had added my MKMapView in a UIScrollView. It seemed not to cause any problems. When I tried removing the MKMapView from the UIScrollView, the warning went away.